# How to record all parameters of any invoked java method dynamically using java agent and ASM?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

What I want to do is to record those parameters and do some comparison with previously input parameters. I need to record parameters for each method invoked, so the length of the parameter list is uncertain.

I think I can parse the method descriptor to know how many parameters this method has. But the problem is, How to record arbitrary number of values from the operand stack?

Now I can only write some sample code. In my `MethodVisitorAdapter` Class:

```java
public void visitMethodInsn(int opc, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean isInterface){
    int n = getParameterCount(desc);
    // How to duplicate arbitrary number of values at operand stack?
    // ...
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass, "recordParameters",
                    /* should be what kind of descriptor (may have arbitrary number of parameters)? */, 
                    false);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(opc, owner, name, desc, isInterface);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `recordParameters` a variable arity method (varargs). It will accept all parameters as a single `Object[]` argument.

So, you'll need to create an array and fill it with (possibly boxed) arguments. The following builder-style class will help to collect the arguments from the stack. It contains `push` methods for all possible types, and also handles autoboxing.

After recording the parameters, the helper can put arguments back onto the stack by calling the corresponding `pop` methods in the reverse order.

```
public class ArgCollector {
    private final Object[] args;
    private int index;

    public ArgCollector(int length) {
        this.args = new Object[length];
        this.index = length;
    }

    public ArgCollector push(Object o) {
        args[--index] = o;
        return this;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        return args[index++];
    }

    public static ArgCollector push(boolean a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(byte    a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(char    a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(short   a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(int     a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(long    a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(float   a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(double  a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }
    public static ArgCollector push(Object  a, ArgCollector c) { return c.push(a); }

    public boolean popZ() { return (boolean) pop(); }
    public byte    popB() { return (byte)    pop(); }
    public char    popC() { return (char)    pop(); }
    public short   popS() { return (short)   pop(); }
    public int     popI() { return (int)     pop(); }
    public long    popJ() { return (long)    pop(); }
    public float   popF() { return (float)   pop(); }
    public double  popD() { return (double)  pop(); }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return args;
    }
}
```

Now, the task is to generate the bytecode equivalent for the following Java code:

```
    ArgCollector collector = new ArgCollector(N);
    recordParameters(
            ArgCollector.push(arg1,
                ArgCollector.push(arg2,
                    ArgCollector.push(argN, collector)))
            .toArray()
    );

    originalMethod(
            collector.popI(),
            collector.popJ(),
            (String) collector.pop()
    );
```

Here is how to do this with ASM:

```
    Type[] args = Type.getArgumentTypes(desc);
    String collector = Type.getInternalName(ArgCollector.class);

    // new ArgCollector(argCount)
    mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, collector);
    mv.visitInsn(DUP);
    mv.visitIntInsn(SIPUSH, args.length);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, collector, "<init>", "(I)V", false);

    // For each argument call ArgCollector.push(arg, collector)
    for (int i = args.length; --i >= 0; ) {
        Type arg = args[i];
        String argDesc = arg.getDescriptor().length() == 1 ? arg.getDescriptor() : "Ljava/lang/Object;";
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, collector, "push",
                "(" + argDesc + "L" + collector + ";)L" + collector + ";", false);
    }

    // Call recordParameters(collector.toArray())
    mv.visitInsn(DUP);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, collector, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;", false);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass, "recordParameters", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);

    // Push original arguments back on stack
    for (Type arg : args) {
        String argDesc = arg.getDescriptor().length() == 1 ? arg.getDescriptor() : "Ljava/lang/Object;";

        mv.visitInsn(DUP);
        if (argDesc.length() == 1) {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, collector, "pop" + argDesc, "()" + argDesc, false);
        } else {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, collector, "pop", "()Ljava/lang/Object;", false);
            if (!arg.getDescriptor().equals("Ljava/lang/Object;")) {
                // Need to cast object arguments to the original type
                mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, arg.getDescriptor());
            }
        }

        // Swap the last argument with ArgCollector, so that ArgCollector is on top again
        if (arg.getSize() == 1) {
            mv.visitInsn(SWAP);
        } else {
            mv.visitInsn(DUP2_X1);
            mv.visitInsn(POP2);
        }
    }

    // Pop off the remaining ArgCollector, and call the original method
    mv.visitInsn(POP);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(opc, owner, name, desc, isInterface);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is really cool but what confuses me is this line `mv.visitVarInsn(arg.getOpcode(ILOAD), index);`, it seems that you want to load the parameters from locals to the stack. But in my knowledge, when `invokevirtual` some instance method, the parameters are in the operand stack, aren't they? Could you expain more about why you use `ILOAD` here?

Comment: @Instein using `ILOAD` is a convention for [`Type.getOpcode(…)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getOpcode-int-) to denote that you want the actual `…load` opcode for the particular type. You are right that this answer assumes that the values are stored in local variables. To use this approach, you would first have to store the invocation arguments into local variable. Also, you need to repeat this pushing afterwards when you want to perform the original invocation instruction.

Comment: @Holger Thanks!! It's clear to me now. If I first store the invocation arguments into the local variable, do I need a sorter or something to prevent the "store" action from affecting the behaviors of following instructions?

Comment: @Instein I updated the answer, so that now arguments are collected from the stack and after calling `recordParameters` are returned back onto the stack.

Comment: @apangin Thanks! It is really clear and useful to me. Actually I am quite new to ASM and not familiar with MethodHandle, I can only fully understand your answer currently. I think it will take me some time to read some materials and to understand other answers...

Comment: @apangin I tried your very first version in the visitCode() method of my adapter, which first load the arguments one by one from the local variables, and package them into a collector object. However, it throws `java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/D, method: add signature: (II)I) Accessing value from uninitialized register 2` on my case. Actually I just use `mv.visitVarInsn(arg.getOpcode(ILOAD), index);` for index 1 and 2 (in visitCode() method after `mv.visitCode();`). When a frame is created, the local variables are initialized by `this` and its arguments. I have no idea why it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

To duplicate an arbitrary sequence of values on the operand stack, there is no way around storing them into new local variables temporarily. Then, push all these values to the operand stack, invoke your reporting method, push them again, and invoke the original method.

A simple approach, avoiding the expenses of [`LocalVariablesSorter`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html), is to check each instruction that uses a local variable and remember the first free index. This requires that the source code has already valid stack map frames, to handle backward branches correctly within a single visiting pass. For code targeting Java 7 or newer, this is mandatory anyway.

Since the code to report the invocation is free of branches and doesn’t need the temporary variables afterwards, we don’t even need an expensive recalculation of stack map frames, as at branch merge points, only the original variables are needed. Only the max stack and locals need recalculation.

To invoke a report method, we can use a holder object, like in [apangin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823781/2711488), but alternatively, we can use the [`java.lang.invoke` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/package-summary.html), which allows us to generate *varargs* collectors with precise method descriptors on-the-fly.

The following code will acquire a [`MethodHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) to `PrintStream.printf(String,Object...)` via a single `ldc` instruction, followed by [binding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#bindTo(java.lang.Object)) `System.out` as first argument, followed by binding a constant `String` suitable for the current number of arguments (and the receiver for non-`static` methods), then adapt the handle calling [`.asVarargsCollector(Object[].class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asVarargsCollector(java.lang.Class))​[`.asType(targetType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asType(java.lang.invoke.MethodType)). The `targetType` is the method type descriptor, with an additional first parameter type for non-static method invocations. This `MethodType` is also loaded with a single `ldc` instruction. Then, the handle can be used by calling [`invokeExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact(java.lang.Object...)) with the same arguments as the actual invocation on the stack.

Only for constructor invocations, the receiver object is omitted, as we are not allowed to use an object before its initialization.

```
{store           n + i } for each argumentᵢ
 ldc              MethodHandle invokeVirtual java/io/PrintStream.printf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 getstatic        java/lang/System.out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 invokevirtual    java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.bindTo(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
 ldc              String containing <method name> and as many %s place holders as needed
 invokevirtual    java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.bindTo(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
 ldc              class [Ljava/lang/Object;
 invokevirtual    java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.asVarargsCollector(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
 ldc              MethodType («actual argument types»)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 invokevirtual    java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.asType(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
{load            n + i } for each argumentᵢ
 invokevirtual    java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.invokeExact(«actual argument types»)Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 pop              // remove the PrintStream return by printf
{load            n + i } for each argumentᵢ
 invoke...        original method
```

The transforming code and example

```
public class LogMethodCalls {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
        MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass(instrument(LogMethodCalls.class
            .getResourceAsStream("LogMethodCalls$ToInstrument.class")));
        runInstrumented();
    }
    private static void runInstrumented() {
        new ToInstrument().run();
    }
    static class ToInstrument implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for(double i: List.of(4, 2, 9, 6)) {
                min = Math.min(min, i);
                max = Math.max(max, i);
            }
            System.out.printf("min %.0f, max %.0f%n", min, max);
        }
    }
    static byte[] instrument(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);

        cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM7, cw) {
            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
                    String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
                return new LogInjector(
                    super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions),
                    access, descriptor);
            }
        }, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }
```

```
    static class LogInjector extends MethodVisitor {
        static final String PS_T = "java/io/PrintStream", PS_S = "L" + PS_T + ";";
        static final String PRINTF_DESC="(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)"+PS_S;
        static final String MH_T="java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle", MH_S="L" + MH_T + ";";

        private int firstUnusedVar;
        public LogInjector(MethodVisitor mv, int acc, String desc) {
            super(Opcodes.ASM7, mv);
            int vars = Type.getArgumentsAndReturnSizes(desc) >> 2;
            if((acc & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) != 0) vars--;
            firstUnusedVar = vars;
        }
        @Override
        public void visitFrame(int type,
            int numLocal, Object[] local, int numStack, Object[] stack) {
            super.visitFrame(type, numLocal, local, numStack, stack);
            firstUnusedVar = Math.max(firstUnusedVar, numLocal);
        }
        @Override
        public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int var) {
            super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var);
            if(opcode == Opcodes.LSTORE || opcode == Opcodes.DSTORE) var++;
            if(var >= firstUnusedVar) firstUnusedVar = var + 1;
        }
        @Override
        public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode,
            String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
            Type[] arg = Type.getArgumentTypes(descriptor);

            int[] vars = storeArguments(arg, opcode, name, owner);

            String reportDesc = getReportDescriptor(owner, descriptor, arg, vars);

            mv.visitLdcInsn(new Handle(Opcodes.H_INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                PS_T, "printf", PRINTF_DESC, false));
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", PS_S);
            bindTo();
            mv.visitLdcInsn(messageFormat(opcode, owner, name, arg));
            bindTo();
            mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getObjectType("[Ljava/lang/Object;"));
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, MH_T,
                "asVarargsCollector", "(Ljava/lang/Class;)"+MH_S, false);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getMethodType(reportDesc));
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, MH_T,
                "asType", "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)"+MH_S, false);
            pushArguments(arg, vars);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                MH_T, "invokeExact", reportDesc, false);
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.POP);

            pushArguments(arg, vars);
            super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
        }

        String getReportDescriptor(
            String owner, String descriptor, Type[] arg, int[] vars) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(owner.length()+descriptor.length()+2);
            sb.append('(');
            if(arg.length != vars.length) {
                if(owner.charAt(0) == '[') sb.append(owner);
                else sb.append('L').append(owner).append(';');
            }
            sb.append(descriptor, 1, descriptor.lastIndexOf(')')+1);
            return sb.append(PS_S).toString();
        }

        int[] storeArguments(Type[] arg, int opcode, String name, String owner) {
            int nArg = arg.length;
            boolean withThis = opcode != Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC && !name.equals("<init>");
            if(withThis) nArg++;
            int[] vars = new int[nArg];
            int slot = firstUnusedVar;
            for(int varIx = nArg-1, argIx = arg.length-1; argIx >= 0; varIx--,argIx--) {
                Type t = arg[argIx];
                mv.visitVarInsn(t.getOpcode(Opcodes.ISTORE), vars[varIx] = slot);
                slot += t.getSize();
            }
            if(withThis)
                mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, vars[0] = slot);
            return vars;
        }
        private void bindTo() {
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, MH_T,
                "bindTo", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)"+MH_S, false);
        }
        private void pushArguments(Type[] arg, int[] vars) {
            int vIx = 0;
            if(arg.length != vars.length)
                mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, vars[vIx++]);
            for(Type t: arg)
                mv.visitVarInsn(t.getOpcode(Opcodes.ILOAD), vars[vIx++]);
        }
        private String messageFormat(int opcode, String owner, String name, Type[] arg){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            switch(opcode) {
                case Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL:
                    if(name.equals("<init>")) {
                        name = Type.getObjectType(owner).getClassName();
                        break;
                    }
                    // else no break
                case Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE: // no break
                case Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL:
                    sb.append("[%s].");
                    break;
                case Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC:
                    sb.append(Type.getObjectType(owner).getClassName()).append('.');
                    break;
            }
            sb.append(name);
            if(arg.length == 0) sb.append("()%n");
            else {
                sb.append('(');
                for(int i = arg.length; i > 1; i--) sb.append("%s, ");
                sb.append("%s)%n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

The example invocation uses Java 9 and relies on a JVM with lazy loading, so it can (re)define the class before actually using it. It might get replaced with an actual Instrumentation scenario, as it is not relevant for the actual transformation logic. In my setup, the example prints

```
java.lang.Object()
java.lang.Integer.valueOf(4)
java.lang.Integer.valueOf(2)
java.lang.Integer.valueOf(9)
java.lang.Integer.valueOf(6)
java.util.List.of(4, 2, 9, 6)
[[4, 2, 9, 6]].iterator()
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].hasNext()
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].next()
[4].intValue()
java.lang.Math.min(2.147483647E9, 4.0)
java.lang.Math.max(-2.147483648E9, 4.0)
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].hasNext()
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].next()
[2].intValue()
java.lang.Math.min(4.0, 2.0)
java.lang.Math.max(4.0, 2.0)
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].hasNext()
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].next()
[9].intValue()
java.lang.Math.min(2.0, 9.0)
java.lang.Math.max(4.0, 9.0)
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].hasNext()
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].next()
[6].intValue()
java.lang.Math.min(2.0, 6.0)
java.lang.Math.max(9.0, 6.0)
[java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListItr@5ce65a89].hasNext()
java.lang.Double.valueOf(2.0)
java.lang.Double.valueOf(9.0)
[java.io.PrintStream@6e5e91e4].printf(min %.0f, max %.0f%n, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2cdf8d8a)
min 2, max 9
```

---

Note that your use case might be simpler. If your logging method is a `static` method, not needing a `PrintStream`, you don’t need binding it. When it doesn’t return a value, you also don’t need to pop it. It would be even simpler when it accepts variable arguments, including the format string or method name. Then, we can pass the string like an ordinary argument, instead of bind it, and since the method handle now is unmodified, it will already be a *varargs* collector when the target method is a *varargs* method:

```
static void yourLog(Object... arg) {
    String name = (String) arg[0]; // or format string
    arg = Arrays.copyOfRange(arg, 1, arg.length);
    …
}
```

```
@Override
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode,
    String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {

    Type[] arg = Type.getArgumentTypes(descriptor);
    int[] vars = storeArguments(arg, opcode, name, owner);
    String reportDesc = getReportDescriptor(owner, descriptor, arg, vars);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(new Handle(Opcodes.H_INVOKESTATIC,
        YOUR_TARGET_TYPE, "yourLog", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false));
    mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getMethodType(reportDesc));
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, MH_T,
        "asType", "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)"+MH_S, false);
    mv.visitLdcInsn(messageFormat(opcode, owner, name, arg));
    pushArguments(arg, vars);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, MH_T, "invokeExact", reportDesc, false);

    pushArguments(arg, vars);
    super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
}

String getReportDescriptor(String owner, String descriptor, Type[] arg, int[] vars) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(owner.length()+descriptor.length()+2);
    sb.append("(Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(arg.length != vars.length) {
        if(owner.charAt(0) == '[') sb.append(owner);
        else sb.append('L').append(owner).append(';');
    }
    sb.append(descriptor, 1, descriptor.lastIndexOf(')')+1);
    return sb.append('V').toString();
}
```

Comment: Like your answer. For myself, I prefer to just replace stuff with an invokedynamic instruction - which enables me to do things "on a higher level" - plain java code dealing with MethodHandles.

Comment: *"there is no way around storing them into new local variables"* - Not necessarily. If arguments are collected into the array, they can be restored back from the array as well.

Comment: @apangin Yeah, boxing and unboxing is fun.

Comment: @apangin then you need to hold the array in a local variable. Or well, you could perhaps do a `dup_x1`/`dup_x2` for the array reference, followed by pushing the index, followed by `swap`, followed by boxing if necessary, followed by `aastore`, then, repeat it for every argument value. Okay, then, there is a way around it, but not really feasible. Extracting the array without using local variables isn’t fun either…

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yeah, `invokedynamic` and an appropriate bootstrap method would also be good. My first approach is a bit involved as I tried to use an already existing method. I thought about `StringConcatFactory` for moment, that might be interesting when logging performance matters…

Comment: Well, I already [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823781/3448419) this before commenting :) A small helper class saves from all boilerplate you describe. But @JohannesKuhn's solution with `invokedynamic` now looks more elegant to me.

Comment: @apangin then, you have hidden the local variables in another method. My statement was more focusing on the impossibility to just duplicate the sequence on the operand stack without another storage, in other words, you can’t do what `dup` etc. do for one or two values for an arbitrary number of values. But it’s always good to have alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

An other option is to replace the `invoke*` instruction with an `invokedynamic`, and providing a bootstrap method:

```
private static final Handle BSM = new Handle(H_INVOKESTATIC, "com/example/Bootstraps", "invokeProxy", "(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;", false);

@Override
public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
    if (opcode == INVOKESPECIAL && name.equals("<init>") {
        super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
        return;
    }
    Type method = Type.getMethodType(descriptor);
    Type[] oldTypes = method.getArgumentTypes();
    final int htype;
    switch (opcode) {
        case INVOKEINTERFACE:
            htype = H_INVOKEINTERFACE;
            break;
        case INVOKESPECIAL:
            htype = H_INVOKESPECIAL;
            break;
        case INVOKESTATIC:
            htype = H_INVOKESTATIC;
            break;
        case INVOKEVIRTUAL:
            htype = H_INVOKEVIRTUAL;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown opcode: " + opcode);
    }
    final Type[] newTypes;
    switch (opcode) {
        case INVOKESPECIAL:
        case INVOKEINTERFACE:
        case INVOKEVIRTUAL:
            newTypes = new Type[oldTypes.length + 1];
            newTypes[0] = Type.getObjectType(owner);
            System.arraycopy(oldTypes, 0, newTypes, 1, oldTypes.length);
            break;
        case INVOKESTATIC:
            newTypes = oldTypes;
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError(); // can not happen.
    }
    Handle h = new Handle(htype, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
    String indyDesc = Type.getMethodType(method.getReturnType(), newTypes).getDescriptor();
    visitInvokeDynamicInsn("_", indyDesc, BSM, h);
}
```

And a simple bootstrap method like this:

```
package com.example; // Change the com/example/Bootstraps if you use a different package.

import java.lang.invoke.CallSite;
import java.lang.invoke.ConstantCallSite;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleInfo;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType;

public class Bootstraps {

    private static final MethodHandle PRINT_ARRAY;

    static {
        try {
            Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodHandle printLn = l.findVirtual(PrintStream.class, "println", methodType(void.class, String.class))
                    .bindTo(System.err);
            MethodHandle arraysDeepToString = l.findStatic(Arrays.class, "deepToString", methodType(String.class, Object[].class));
            PRINT_ARRAY = MethodHandles.foldArguments(
                    MethodHandles.dropArguments(printLn, 1, Object[].class), arraysDeepToString);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    public static CallSite invokeProxy(Lookup lookup, String name, MethodType type, MethodHandle target) {
        Object method = lookup.revealDirect(target);
        MethodHandle printArgsMH = MethodHandles.foldArguments(target, 
                PRINT_ARRAY.asCollector(Object[].class, type.parameterCount() + 1)
                    .bindTo(method)
                    .asType(type.changeReturnType(void.class)))
                .asType(type);
        return new ConstantCallSite(printArgsMH);
    }
}
```

Which probably looks more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: my God this is beautiful!!

Comment: Has a few problems through: You can't intercept `invokespecial` for constructors, and it requires the bytecode version to be 51 or greater (which is also the version where you can't use `JSR`/`RET`). Other than that, it simplifies instrumentation by quite a bit from my experience. Also, you can intercept `GETSTATIC`, `PUTSTATIC`, `GETFIELD` and `SETFIELD` - the set\* ones only for non-final fields.

Comment: That’s what I also had in mind when thinking about `invokedynamic` though I’d avoid `revealDirect` when possible; the types are available anyway and the target method name could be provided as method name of the `invokedynamic` instruction by .ust replacing `"_"` with `name`. More isn’t necessary for logging, usually. The inability to do this for constructor invocations is the only drawback. My solution also assumed Java 7 minimum, as it relies on stack map frames. I don’t think that support for older versions is important.

Comment: You actually need the target class and the name. Yes, you can encode that with `com/example/SomeType.method` as name. Has it's benefits. The basic idea behind this code is that a bootstrap method that just `return new ConstantCallSite(target);` should not change the behavior of the program, even if you [invokedynamic all the things (Slide 51)](https://www.slideshare.net/DanHeidinga/invokedynamic-evolution-of-a-language-feature) .